# Can't compile after installing ngx-device-detector

Tags: angular

After installing the ngx-device-detector, i got these scary error when executing `ng serve`:

[image]

[image]

After commenting the `import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';` - the code has been compiled again.

Does anybody has an idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: And could you please provide more details? Some part of code would be great if possible.